# Error in reading input to an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I was writing sorting algorithm when I encountered the following error.

Code:

```
int main()
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n;
    int a[100];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    //or use getlinee as getline (cin, fullName);
    int swap_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
            swap_count = swap_count + 1;
        }
    }

    if (swap_count != 0) {
        for (int p = n; p > 1; --p) {
            for (int q = 0; q < p - 1; ++q) {
                if (a[q] > a[q + 1]) {
                    int temp_var = a[q];
                    a[q] = a[q + 1];
                    a[q + 1] = temp_var;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
1 5 2
```

Output:

```
1 5 1878000832
```

On repeating with multiple values I found the last value of the series is being read wrong.

**What is the reason for this problem and how do I resolve it?**

Note: I know there are many alternative ways to input but I wanted to know why this one isn't working.

Comment: Check the indexing in your first loop again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading elements only from `a[1]`, but your sorting begins from `a[0]`.

Change

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

to read data also to `a[0]`.